# Gateway for Synapse given it has managed private VNET

Tags: powerbi, azure-synapse, gateway, vnet

Do I have to install a data gateway (standard/private) on synapse for PowerBI workspace if it has managed private VNET.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access data sources that can't inject a private endpoint into your managed private VNET then yes, you need a gateway (SHIR).